# TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration with functions

Tags: python, function, csv

I am coding a shopping list program and the user can choose whether they add an item, edit an item or view the list. I have made them all functions so the user can input the necessary information and the program calls the function. All the items are saved to a csv file.

Here is the AddItem function:

```
import csv
def AddItem(name,shop, qantity, priority_level,price,bought):
    with open("C:\\Users\\sophie\\Documents\\Sophie\\Homework\\Year 11\\Computer Science\\ShoppingList.csv","a", newline = '') as csvfile:
        fieldnames=['Name','Shop','Quantity','Price','Priority_Level','Bought']
        writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames==fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'Name':name, 'Shop': shop, 'Quantity': quantity, 'Price':price,'Priority_Level':priority_level, 'Bought': bought})
        print('You have now added ',name,' to your shopping list.')
```

Here is the code for the user inputting the specific details:

```
ModeChose=='A':
name=input('Please enter the name of the item you want to add. ')
shop=input('Please enter the shop you will buy it from, if you don’t know, press zero. ')
int_quantity=input('Please enter the quantity of the item you will buy, if you don’t know, press zero. ')
int_priority_level=int(input('Please enter the priority level of the item you will buy, if you don’t know, press zero (1 is high priority, all the way to 5 which is low priority). '))
quantity=str(int_quantity)
priority_level=str(int_priority_level)
int_price=int(input('Please enter the price of the product roundest to the nearest pound, if you don’t know, press zero. '))
price=str(int_price)
bought=input('Please enter Y if you have bought the item and N is you haven’t. ')
AddItem(name, shop, quantity, priority_level, price, bought)
```

Here is the error I get when I run it:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sophie\Documents\Sophie\Homework\Year 11\Computer Science\ShoppingList.py", line 103, in <module>
    AddItem(name, shop, quantity, priority_level, price, bought)
  File "C:\Users\sophie\Documents\Sophie\Homework\Year 11\Computer Science\ShoppingList.py", line 8, in AddItem
    writer.writeheader()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\csv.py", line 141, in writeheader
    header = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, self.fieldnames))
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

Comment: `fieldnames=fieldnames`. Just one `=` not two.

Comment: Thank you, it works

Answer (score 2):

At a glance it could be this line:

`writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames==fieldnames)`

Make sure to use a single = not ==. What your code currently does is set the second positional argument to DictWriter to a `True` / `False` boolean value. What you want to do is set the keyword argument `fieldnames` to the appropriate object.

Comment: good catch. so `fieldnames` is probably accepted but as _boolean_. So typo question, but not trivial to figure out. So +1

Comment: Moral of the story: fail early. I'd consider it a bug in the `csv` module that `DictWriter` doesn't catch this before actually trying to use the value as an argument to `zip`.

Comment: @chepner csv module could be modified to accept no positional arguments after the first one, yes...